# Not removing a substring from a string

Tags: c#, substring

I am trying to remove a substring from a string in this simple code. But c# is not removing it:

```
stringCmd = "Haha WoWI am in love!"
stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);
```

After removing it should be **"Haha am in love!"**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Its working  and giving the result `Haha am in love!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`string.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) method returns new string without modifying the one passed as parameter, so you have to assign it back to your variable:

```
stringCmd = stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);
```

You should also be aware that `string`s in .NET are immutable. You can read more about that on MSDN: [`string` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

String are immutable in .NET

```
stringCmd = "Haha WoWI am in love!"
stringCmd = stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, thus it does not affect the string but rather, returns a new one:

```
string stringCmd = "Haha WoWI am in love!"
string modified = stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);
Console.WriteLine(modified);
```

Answer (score 3):

This method returns a string with the specified substring removed. So you need to apply it to another string:

```
string myString = stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);
```

or you could apply it back to itself:

```
stringCmd = stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing 
stringCmd = stringCmd.Remove(stringCmd.IndexOf("WoW"), 5);